# maven-war-plugin basedir <workspace>/target/dist does not exist

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin

We're trying to build a Java-based project with Maven (v3.5.4) and with the JDK 1.8.92 but we getting an error `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project embedded-analytics: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war failed: basedir /data/jenkins/workspace/test-mansing-embedded/target/dist does not exist -> [Help 1]`

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                  <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>target/dist</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>main/main.js</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                  </webResources>
                </configuration>
             </plugin>
```

1. The permission on the workspace directory looks OK.
2. I tried adding a version for maven-war-plugin but no luck.

Any suggestion is really apperciated.